# Remove Object from list when key element is not present in springboot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is my code for list in which I am removing object from the list if it doesnt match certain condition ,but in some case where I dont have such key available then I am getting exception , such as if name element doesnt exist in one of my object its throws an err , I dont want to show err simply I want to just ignore from the list if the key element is not present , small json I can show for example can be ..

```
@Override
    public List<Item> getcollectionfromapi(List<String> itemids) throws Exception {
        List<Item> collection = itemRepository.findById(itemids);
        Predicate<Item> name = item -> item.getProduct().getName() == null;
        Predicate<Item> names = item -> item.getProduct().getName().length() == 0;
        Predicate<Item> datas = item -> item.getDatas().equals("data") == false;
        collection.removeIf(name);
        collection.removeIf(names);
        collection.removeIf(datas);
        return collection;
    }
}

SampleJson:-
    [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "datas": "data",
        "product": {
          "name": "Transport",
          "value":"1"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "product": {
          "value":"2"
        }
      }
    ]
    

return only

[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "datas": "data",
    "product": {
      "name": "Transport",
      "value":"1"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you paste the error/exception you get when the item product name is missing?

Comment: "message": "Error : Cannot invoke \"String.equals(Object)\" because the return value of \"com.bhushan.Item.getName()\" is null",
same with datas field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Predicate<Item> name = item -> StringUtils.isBlank(item.getProduct().getName());
Predicate<Item> datas = item -> "data".equals(item.getDatas()) == false;
```